# Update no me funciona

Tags: php, mysql

necesito realizar una suma con el método UPDATE, trayendo el valor del campo suma de la tabla cuenta, para sumar el número del valor obtenido 1+1, pero resulta que al momento de hacer la suma me da como resultado 3 y de ahí ya no quiere seguir sumando.
No se si sea por la forma en que lo tenga estructurado o porque estoy haciendo mal la sentencia. Por tu atención muchas gracias.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)

 {
echo"usuario existe";

} else{

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cuenta";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $numero=$row["suma"]+1;


 $hace_suma = "UPDATE cuenta SET suma='".$numero ."' WHERE id = 5";
$result = $conn->query($hace_suma);
}
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que realmente quieres conseguir? ¿Porque obtienes todos los datos de una tabla pero después solo modificas el valor con  Id = 5? Analizando tu código, te va a recorrer el bucle con todos los valores de la tabla que estás consultando, pero sólo vas a ver reflejado en la BD la última iteración de ese bucle, que intuyo que el resultado es 2+1, y por eso siempre te aparece 3.

Comment: MySQL sabe sumar directamente, intenta con `"UPDATE cuenta SET suma = suma + 1 WHERE id = 5"`. Lo único extraño que veo aquí es que el ID siempre es 5.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pude solucionar mi problema